# Confused by squaring macro SQR in c

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

This question was asked to me in a mock interview...Really got surprised to find awkward answers...

consider a macro:

```
#define SQR(x) (x*x)
```

**Example 1:**

```
SQR(2) //prints 4
```

**Example 2:**

If SQR(1+1) is given it doesn't sum `(1+1)` to `2` but rather ...

```
SQR(1+1) //prints 3
```

Awkward right? What is the reason? How does this code work?

NOTE: I searched SO but couldn't find any relevant questions. If there are any kindly please share it!

Comment: Hint: Read the output of the **pre**-processor.

Comment: `SQR(1+1)` expand to `(1+1*1+1)` == 3, change to ((x)*(x))

Comment: This is the C-preprocessor. You could achieve the same behavior if you used the C-preprocessor with any language.

Comment: see <a href="http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Why_not_macros">this link</a> for why macros can totally suck. Also, see this comment to see why I suck at html. (seriously, wtf, why doesnt my link work?)

Comment: Thank u all!!! It was a piece of info for beginner lik me!!! I love SO!!!

Comment: @ash because is html rather than the mini markdown... click the help button below  or format like: `[link](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Why_not_macros)`

Comment: ah ha! in which case, I meant to do this: [why not macros?](http://iso-9899.info/wiki/Why_not_macros)

Comment: @abu Interesting post for you: [MAX using typeof extension of gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039325/max-using-typeof-extension-of-gcc?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: The title is about `sqrt`, but nothing int he question is about `sqrt`.

Comment: https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/42

Comment: Try compiling `SQR("hello")`.  Macros are evil.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`SQR(1+1)` expands to `1+1*1+1` which is 3, not 4, correct?

A correct definition of the macro would be

```
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))
```

which expands to  `(1+1)*(1+1)` and, **more important**, shows you one of the reasons you shouldn't use macros where they aren't needed. The following is better:

```
inline int SQR(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Furthermore: `SQR(i++)` would be **undefined behavior** if `SQR` is a macro, and completely correct if `SQR` is a function.

Comment: Of course, even the "corrected" macro can still surprise you when it evaluates the argument twice.

Comment: @MikeSeymour this what you had in mind?

Comment: Hi Luchian. It's simple to see that `x*x` is wrong. Also, `(x*x)` just puts that in parenthses. Can you come up with an example where `(x)*(x)` is more wrong than the final solution `((x)*(x))`? I think we need an operator that has higher precedence than `*`. I can think of `sizeof SQR(x)` go wrong. Is there a more realistic example than that?

Comment: Also, do you know why SQR(i++) is UB? A reference to the C++ standard would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that macros are doing textual substition before it is compiled, so the macro expands to `1+1*1+1` which means `1+(1*1)+1` because of the mathematical rules, which in turn evaluates to `1+1+1` = 3 which is the correct result.
That's why you should put that in brackets.

```
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Answer (score 5):

That is why you *always* put arguments to macros into ():

```
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))
```