# Value of a Pre-processor directive statement in C

Tags: c

So, I'm confused why the output of i would be 27 and not 343

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#define x 5+2
void main() {
int i;
i=x*x*x;
printf("%d",i); }
```

Comment: It expands to `5+2*5+2*5+2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The need for parentheses in macros in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c)

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [Confused by squaring macro SQR in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071504/995714), [Incorrect answer from #define SQR(x) (x*x)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25822341/995714). And this should be explained in every book. [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/995714)

Comment: OT:  regarding the statement: `void main() {`   1) in C, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Note: they both have a return type of `int`, not `void`.   This statement will cause a compiler to output a warning message.

Answer (score 13):

Let's expand what you did, preprocessor is a dummy thing that just replaces the token with text

```
i = 5+2*5+2*5+2; // <- 27
```

if you modify `define` to be `#define x (5+2)` all should work as expected.

Comment: That's general advice too: always parenthesise a macro expression.

Comment: FYI, macro replacement replaces preprocessor tokens, not text. One difference is that macro replacement cannot form new preprocessor tokens (except by use of `#` or `##` operators).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Nice catch, will replace `text` with `token`.